# Automatically Adding New Grails Versions to the Jenkins Grails

Tags: grails, plugins, jenkins, automation

Is there a way to configure a new Grails installation automatically?  We
usually go into the /config page on our Jenkins server and add a Grails
installation there by hand (we use the automatic download feature, but
that's different).

I thought we may be able to programatically add something like the following
to the com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsInstallation.xml file:

```
<com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsInstallation>
  <name>grails-2.4.3</name>
  <home></home>
  <properties>
    <hudson.tools.InstallSourceProperty>
      <installers>
        <com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsInstaller>
          <id>2.4.3</id>
        </com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsInstaller>
      </installers>
    </hudson.tools.InstallSourceProperty>
  </properties>
</com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsInstallation>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, even if we tell Jenkins to reload the
configuration from disk.

-Kevin

Comment: Have you considered using the Grails wrapper? Since I switched to this, I have not had to worry about Grails versioning and Jenkins supports it very well ...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to install grails version automatically, is to use the grails wrapper.

Go to you project and do

`grails wrapper`

This installs the wrapper to your project. Check this code in. In Jenkins there should be an option to "use grails wrapper"

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the wrapper? It's pretty simple to install and you can control the grails version for your project from the project.

If you update to another version you don't have to go to Jenkins admin to install the new version. Just upgrade your app, install the new grails-wrapper, commit the changes and push them. Jenkins automatically will use the new version.